# Power Series with Random Coefficients

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, power-series, stochastic-analysis

First of all, I don't know how such series are called, but I assume there exists some theoretical work behind that kind of power series. So for example assume we have the random sequence $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ with $a_n\in\{-1,1\}$ and $P(a_n=-1)=P(a_n=1)=\frac{1}{2}$, e.g. $(1,-1,-1,1,1,\dots)$, and define the power series $$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{a_n}{n!}x^n.$$
As example, the series could look like $$f(x)=1-x+\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^3}{6}-\frac{x^4}{24}+\dotsm$$ or
$$f(x)=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^4}{24}-\dotsm.$$
Clearly the resulting series will lie (in absolute terms) between $e^x$ and $-e^{-x}$, but can we write down further properties, e.g. if we averge over all possible function $$\lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{f^{(1)}(x)+f^{(2)}(x)+\dotsm+f^{(N)}(x)}{N}$$what would be the result, my intuition says $0$, but I'm definitly not sure. If anyone knows some theory behind these series or how they're called, it would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd have to be clear about what such a series means, convergence and all that. But you do know the finite sum $Y = \sum_{n = 0}^N a_n z^n/n!$ has mean zero and, assuming $a_0, a_1, \dots$ are all independent, has variance
\begin{equation} \text{var}\,Y = \sum_{n = 0}^N \frac{z^{2n}}{n! n!}
\end{equation}
which tends to $I_0(2z)$ as $N \rightarrow \infty$. Same result, for example, as when each $a_0, a_1, \dots$ are normally distributed with zero mean and unit variance.

If you want to dig in deeper, you might take advantage of the fact that each $a_n$ has characteristic function $\cos t$, so the finite sum will
have characteristic function $\cos(tz^0/0!)\cdots\cos(tz^N/N!)$.

Comment: You're right, I could look at the partial sums and try do deduce further properties from there. Do you know of a general theory behind these series or if they're useful?